# How to connect Mongoose in Bluemix

Tags: node.js, mongoose, ibm-cloud

I created my first appication in ibm bluemix and I added the service mongodb:

```
{
  "mongodb-2.4": {
    "name": "mongodb-27",
    "label": "mongodb-2.4",
    "plan": "100",
    "credentials": {
      "hostname": "192.****.15",
      "host": "192.****.15",
      "port": 10021,
      "username": "7d5be****9358a",
      "password": "aede****dce9a",
      "name": "43c5a237-9f3a-4df0-85f7-4df9a2d26a5d",
      "db": "db",
      "url": "mongodb://7d5be****9358a:aede****dce9a@192.****.15:10021/db"
    }
  }
}
```

Then i tried to bind mongodb service using mongoose:

```
var db;
if (process.env.VCAP_SERVICES) {
   var env = JSON.parse(process.env.VCAP_SERVICES);
   if (env['mongodb-2.2']) {
        db = mongoose.createConnection(env['mongodb-2.2'][0].credentials.url);
        console.log ("Connected to mongodb-2.2 service");
    } 
    if (env['mongodb-2.4']) {
        db = mongoose.createConnection(env['mongodb-2.4'][0].credentials.url);
        console.log ("Connected to mongodb-2.4 service");
    }
} else {
    db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://7d5be****9358a:aede****dce9a@192.155.243.15:10021/db');
}
```

But it doesnt work. I did two option with mongodb-2.2 and mongodb-2.4 service because all tutorials have mongodb-2.2 but i saw that mine is 2.4

I wanted to create an app with a REST API using mongoose + ember, but i need to solve the DB connection fisrt.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work what do you mean? Do you see any output in the log? This is failing whilst running on Bluemix, is that correct? as you are not able to access the mongodb service from an app outside of Bluemix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try like below,it will remove the dependency to explicitly mentioning the mongodb version :

```
/*var mongoUrl; */
 var db;
if (process.env.VCAP_SERVICES)
{
      var env = JSON.parse(process.env.VCAP_SERVICES);
      for (var svcName in vcapServices)
      {
            if (svcName.match(/^mongo.*/))
            {
               db = mongoose.createConnection(env['mongodb-2.2'][0].credentials.url);
               console.log ("Connected to mongodb-2.2 service");
               /*
                  mongoUrl = vcapServices[svcName][0].credentials.uri;
                 mongoUrl = mongoUrl || vcapServices[svcName][0].credentials.url;
                 break; */
            }
        }
        /*var mongo = require('mongoskin'); /
       /*var db = mongo.db(mongoUrl, {native_parser:true}); */
```

P.S: Via commented code,I had tried to use a alternative to establish connection to mongodb via Bluemix,you can try both..

Also,I would suggest to use package.json entries like below:

```
    "mongodb": "*",
    "mongoskin": "*"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use env variable VCAP_SERVICEs in optimised manner to match mongodb version.
like below:

```
for (var svcName in vcapServices)
{
if (svcName.match(/^mongo.*/)){
 if (env['mongodb-2.2']) {
        db = mongoose.createConnection(env['mongodb-2.2'][0].credentials.url);
        console.log ("Connected to mongodb-2.2 service");
    } 
    if (env['mongodb-2.4']) {
        db = mongoose.createConnection(env['mongodb-2.4'][0].credentials.url);
        console.log ("Connected to mongodb-2.4 service");
    }
} else {
    db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://7d5be****9358a:aede****dce9a@192.155.243.15:10021/db');
}
```

here are few useful links for you >
http://ryanjbaxter.com/2014/03/03/moving-an-existing-node-js-app-to-run-on-bluemix/
http://blog.mongodb.org/post/6587009156/cloudfoundry-mongodb-and-nodejs